# PhoneGap Build version 2.7.0 ignoring fullscreen preference in config.xml on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have followed the very clear instructions on this page:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

I have included the following line in my config.xml file (which is indeed located at the top level of my app):
`<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />`

And yet the status bar at the top of the screen remains.

Here is my full config.xml file if it helps..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.universeprojects.voidspace"
    versionCode="10" 
    version   = "0.1.2b">

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>VoidSpace - DevServer</name>

<description>
    This is a special version of VoidSpace that connects to the development server.
</description>

<author href="https://voidspace.ca" email="support@universeprojects.com">
    Nikolas Gauvreau
</author>

<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />

<icon src="icon.png" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I too have noticed that PGB ignores many of the documented preferences. Would love to see a response that solves this answer!

Comment: Which Phonegap version are you using and What Android version are you testing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your `config.xml` file, modified as you need, at the same directory, as the `index.html` file:

[image]

**Note:** in this case, we have our application built in the `public/` dir. So all the stylesheets and javascripts are already compiled and placed within one.

And now just observe the magic!

Answer (score 0):

Add `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` in this path:
res/xml/config.xml.

It really worked for me