# Phonegap + Android: I can't set app fullscreen mode to false

Tags: android, cordova

My application is not responding to the config.xml line:

```
 preference name="fullscreen" value="false"
```

It continues hidding the status bar. I'm working with Phonegap 3.4 and testing on Android 4.4.2.

I tried this code with a clean starter project created by phonegap create command.

Comment: Perhaps this bug ['Hydration iOS ignores config.xml preferences #36'](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/36) is related? Or is your question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236935/phonegap-build-version-2-7-0-ignoring-fullscreen-preference-in-config-xml-on-and?rq=1 ?

Comment: This sounds like your problem but on iOS instead of Android: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19005439/1112472

Comment: No, I have this issue on Android. My problem is quite similar with the problem exposed in the link that M. Mimpen gave me, but the solution provided there not work to me (And that problem is related to Phonegap Build). It's a strange issue due... :S

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the config.xml file in here: platforms\android\res\xml